# How to remove the file at /tmp/ folder from kernel code..?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have created and opened `/tmp/output` file from my kernel character driver code using `filp_open()`. And I am able to do close it using `filp_close()`. But after unloading the module it is not removing the file `/tmp/output`.
What should I do to remove it?

Comment: Assuming `/tmp/output` is a valid path seems wrong to me.

Comment: Does the function you passed to `module_exit` remove that file?  I'll echo @MichaWiedenmann though: you shouldn't assume it's a valid path, especially since `/tmp` is world writable.